# Service Battery issue

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery

My battery is in 'service-required' state since couple years back. I am in South Korea and the first apple branch will open in Seoul in March this year. I wonder if this is part of the reason why it takes so long to retrieve the needed components as they say.

It was to take about 10 working days here to fix it, at the cost of apx. 200 USD. More because of the time, as I'm heavily dependent on the computer I understand so little, I decided to stick with it. It turns out I have another friend in the same situation in this country.

It's uncomfortable that the laptop has to be connected to the cord at all times, but without it I have troubles to deal with anyway. I found out about the kits provided by [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Kits/Macbook-Pro-Retina-Battery-Kits), but they don't ship overseas. Plus, lithium-ion batteries have special rules at the customs of the airport; not a daily convenience stuff to ask for friends to smuggle in when they visit for holidays.

So I have been wondering for quite long, if you take it to an apple branch in America or other countries with good industrial network, how long does it cost to fix this state?

I currently use Macbook Pro of 2012. (OS: High Sierra 10.13.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bit painful. I would ask if they have a mail in option.

I just had my MacBook repaired for this issue and it took me 30 minutes on the phone to report the issue / confirm my shipping address. I received a pre-paid FedEx container around 4 PM. I dropped it off to FedEx at 7 PM - it entered repair in Houston, TX around 5 AM the next day and was back to shipping 6 hours later. Now, this was perfect timing and near a large city in the US - but the machine was out of my hands for a day and a morning.

I can see them quoting 10 days if they are not going to order parts - and if the shipping of the parts takes 2-3 days and they allow for the chance that some other part fails and an extra time for shipping / testing.

I see our Apple Stores quoting 5 to 7 days for repairs since they can't be as efficient or stocked as the repair centers for mail in service.

Answer (score 2):

Wait depends on two factors: a) whether the Apple store or the service provider has the battery in stock; wait for delivery from Apple is probably a day or two; and b) the existence (or not) of sufficient techs at the store or shop to do the work that customers have ordered. If work is backed up, it'll take longer.

A battery change should take .5 - 1 hr, and if the customer is lucky (i.e., battery in stock and a tech available), might be able to be accomplished while the customer waits.

Comment: Just a word of caution - some MacBook and MacBook Pro batteries are now glued to internal frame parts and it can take quite a bit longer - especially if a fragile cable bends or other parts need to be repaired. Yes - the vast majority can still get done in an hour - but it's not like the original unibody Mac where we could take apart 10 screws - slide in a rectangular battery and test in 15 minutes or less.

Comment: bmike is correct for newer machines. The OP's machine is a mid-2012 model, and its battery will not be glued in place.